# Excel copy-paste to SQL Server sets BIT type to null

Tags: excel, ssms, copy-paste

I am copying some table data from one database to another (identical table schema, table is empty in one database, I am copying all the rows from the other database).

I'm doing this by running a select in SQL Server Management Studio, copying the results to Excel to inspect, then copying from Excel to SSMS' 'Edit Top 200 Rows'.

The problem is that some columns have BIT type.  The values display as 1/0 in SSMS select and as 1/0 in Excel.  But after pasting in to SSMS, the values all become null.

BIT type will display as 1/0 but will not parse 1/0 as input?  Does it mean BIT type is effectively not supported for copy-paste operation?

SSMS is version 10, Excel version 2003 SP3.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the BIT values need to be True and False to parse correctly:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330293/1-and-0-not-recognised-as-boolean

It does seem not very consistent or user friendly that the values display as 1 / 0 but will only parse from True / False.